# How to retrieve httponly cookies with IE selenium driver?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, python, ie

By my research so far, IE  selenium webdriver (for IE10 or 11) is not able to retrieve `httponly` cookies.

So code like this can return a full set of cookies including those set to `httponly` if I am using Chrome or FF driver

```
self.driver.get_cookies()
```

However for the IE driver, the`httponly` cookies will be missing from the result

I just want to confirm it is the behaviour as of now, and if there is any workaround other than unsetting the `httponly` flag on the server side.

P.S. Unable to create new 'IE' tag so tagging this question with `ie9`

Comment: Can you get the full list and parse out the http from https?  Optionally you can get the original get_cookies() functions from selenium and write a custom one instead.  Either way I'd think you would have to get the full set and then parse out the ones that don't match your target.

Answer (score 1):

- This is one of the **open issue**
- **Work around** is :

  1. Turn off the HTTP-only flag when running my site in testing mode
  2. I use Django for my server so I had to create a special test_settings.py file with `SESSION_COOKIE_HTTPONLY = False` in it

I borrow answer from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29775006/retrieving-all-cookies-from-ie-using-python)